# Given $v(t)=2\sin(e^t/4)+1$ how do i find the average velocity of the particle for the time period $0-6$.

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-derivative

I'm also given acceleration and $x(0)=2$ but i'm not sure any of that information will be beneficial helping to solve this problem.

I believe I have to first integrate the equation for velocity so I can use the equation: 
s(b)-s(a)/b-a, but i'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: The time average of $v(t)$ over $[0, 6]$ is ${1\over 6}\int_0^6{v(t)\,dt}$. Is the difficulty that you can't evaluate the integral?

Comment: Yes, that is the difficulty i'm having.

Comment: Instead of $s(b)-s(a)/b-a$ do you mean $\dfrac{s(b)-s(a)}{b-a}$?

Comment: Yes that was a formatting error on my part.

Comment: So I believe I answered the question below, but it seems you are in an introductory course and the answer is sophisticated. Were you supposed to use technology to integrate numerically? Does the problem have a typo?

Answer (score 1):

With the substitution $u = e^t$, the problem becomes $$1 + {1\over 3}\int_{{1/4}}^{\exp{\!(6)}/4}{{\sin{u}\over u}\,du}\,.$$

The integral $\int_0^z{{\sin{u}\over u}\,du}$ defines the so-called Sine Integral function, denoted ${\rm Si}(z)$. So the answer to your problem is expressible as $$1 + {1\over 3}\left[{\rm Si}\left({e^6\over 4}\right) - {\rm Si}\left({1\over 4}\right)\right] \approx 1.437\,.$$

Alternatively, you could use technology to integrate numerically from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is not a real answer but I don't think that function can be integrated!
I may be wrong thou'.